# How do I switch my HUD view in tf2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

On YouTube I see a lot of people whose HUD shows the whole weapon without it in their face. The weapon was a bit more away from the screen. How do I use this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the field of view in your graphic settings. The default is 70 or 75 I think. You can set it up to 90, this will increase your field of view which gives you a better overview.

You can change it using the commands too:

```
viewmodel_fov <yourValue>
```